# jquery start function on page load

Tags: jquery, load, handler

I want this effect to start when the page is loaded. Now it starts when you click on the layer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function () {
        $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I also used `.load(function)`, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function(){
  $('div').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Trigger a click on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div").click(function () { 
        $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000); 
    }).trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: If you want to have all div elements pulsate on load and every time you click one of them us this. I see no reason for downvote, this is perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Well in his question, he said he wanted the code to run as he programmed it, when the page loaded, so...that's what this does, lol

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the '.click' listener.  Then just use:

```
$(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
```

**Note:** If you want to have one div element pulsate only on load, provided you replace $(this) with proper selector, use this.

Comment: If you want to have one div element pulsate only on load, provided you replace $(this) with proper selector, use this.

Comment: That is what I meant when I wrote "you can attach the 'this' to anything you want".  I should have been more explicit.

Comment: Sorry, I thought to differentiate a bit, since other answer is also correct, but for different scenario.

Comment: I agree with what you said, I really should have been more explicit.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This won't happen on load necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
});
```

This doesn't depend on setting `this` (bad, `this` should refer to scope) or triggering an event.